Do we spell out the word "two" or use the digit "$2$" in a mathematics-based essay?
I've heard that when doing formal writing, we normally spell out numbers under $10$, but in mathematics we use digits for all numbers.
For example, we use the word "two" when writing essays but the number "$2$" in mathematical situations.
When doing a mathematical essay, should I use "two" or "$2$" in the following scenarios?
$1.$ "The number [two/$2$] is the only even prime"
$2.$ "Graph a function of [two/$2$] variables"

I don't believe there is a hard and fast rule.

If it helps:  from a purely personal perspective, I sometimes use the two options to distinguish one sort of thing from another.  Thus, I'd be inclined to write "Consider three distinct odd primes, like $3, 5, 17$".  Again, not claiming a general rule here, just personal habit.

The numeral 2 is generally fine, unless at the beginning of a sentence.  Using a numeral at the beginning of a sentence can be confusing, so write "Two" instead.

This is really a question of style, more than anything else.  On matters of style, you should consult a relevant style guide—for most mathematical writing, the guide of choice is the AMS Style Guide.  In section 13.1, the AMS advises

Generally, spell out single-digit numbers and use digits for 10 and above
when they appear in the text. However, for numbers less than 10, note
the author’s use of numerals and spelled-out numbers for any patterns
and mark these on the style sheet. For instance, some common phrases
that include an acceptable use of single-digit numbers are “rank 1” or
“rank one”, “codimension 2” or “codimension two”, “3-dimensional”
or “three-dimensional”. The use of single digits is acceptable if used
consistently.
In most cases, you should stet the author’s use of a numeral
or a spelled-out number.

In a nutshell, this says that an AMS editor should prefer spelling out numbers smaller than 10, and using numerals for anything larger, but editors should stet (let stand) an author's original use unless there is a compelling reason not to—basically, it is ultimately up to the author.
As a matter of personal preference, I generally adhere to this rule with two major exceptions (there are likely others, but these are the important ones which come to mind):

I don't like to begin sentences with "notation".  A sentence should begin with a capitalized word.  When a sentence looks like it might start with notation, I will typically try to rework the sentence so that it doesn't—this might require moving things around, or simply spelling out some numeral.  So

✅ The number 2 is the only even prime number.
❌ 2 is the only even prime number.
✅ Two is the only even prime number.
✅ The only even prime is 2.


Numbers which are numbers in the context of the mathematics being discussed should be written as numerals.  That is, if the number itself is part of the mathematical object being described, it should be left as a numeral.  Otherwise, spell it out if it is smaller than 10.

❌ The only solution to the equation is one.
✅ The only solution to the equation is 1.
❌ There are 2 solutions to the equation.
✅ There are two solutions to the equation.




I agree with all of this, except that for some reason, I find "Two is the only even prime number" fairly jarring. I'm not sure I can completely explain this, since I find "rank one" less jarring. But my general personal preference is to write the numeral when used in the context of a formal mathematical object, and to spell it when it gives the number of items in an English sentence. Thus, "the two operators commute with each other".

@user43208 I also find "Two is the only even prime" awkward (per my second preference).  In that sentence, "2" is a number qua number, and (in my opinion) should be written as a numeral.  Hence I, personally, would prefer either of the other checked options.

Yes to this answer, and to @user43208's comment. Regarding the second line from the last: while I'd definitely write There are two solutions to the equation: 3 and 7 and am partial to There are two solutions to the equation (mainly for consistency), and I frequently find myself deliberately defying the style guide to write There are 2 solutions to the equation when not specifying the solutions within the sentence.
